# Pymongo "aggregate" failed with $convert and $toString, but it's not because of version

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Descripción

I have this and I need to convert the ObjectId to String because in the models collection it is as a string.

```
match = {'$match': { ...simplematch}}

uidConvertion = {'$addFields': {
    "uid": {"$convert": {"input": "$_id", "to": "string"}}}
}

join = {'$lookup': {
        'from': 'model',
        'localField': 'uid',
        'foreignField': 'exampleCollection',
        'as': 'models'
}}
res = db.exampleCollection.aggregate([
    match,
    uidConvertion,
    join
])
```

But ...

```
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 527, in aggregate
   return self.client._retryable_read(
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1525, in _retryable_read
   return func(session, server, sock_info, secondary_ok)
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/aggregation.py", line 137, in get_cursor
   result = sock_info.command(
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 710, in command
   return command(self, dbname, spec, secondary_ok,
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 158, in command
   helpers._check_command_response(
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 167, in _check_command_response
   raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unrecognized expression '$convert', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Unrecognized expression '$convert'", 'code': 168, 'codeName': 'InvalidPipelineOperator'}
```

I am connected to a database in ATLAS and to check I looked at the version of the database with `db.version()` and it turns out that it is `4.4.10`. I looked at many similar errors and it was because they had mongo in version lower than 4 and I looked at the pymongo version to try to find the error but it is `3.12`.

also happened to me with $toString

The only thing left for me to do is to save with the objectId

Comment: That aggregation worked when I tried it.  Error 168 is returned from the mongod server.  Check the log to make sure it is connecting where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$project` and `$toString` for this. The following example is a rough proof of concept (since I'm not sure what your data looks like in Mongo).

You can check out a [live demo of this query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hcGnyOEHM-6).

### Database

Consider the following database:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "_id": ObjectId("123456789101112131415161")
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "_id": ObjectId("333336789101112131415161")
  }
]
```

### Query

We can use the following query to get the `_id` as a string.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "Joe"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      uid: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      },
      name: 1
    }
  },
  // {
  //   $lookup goes here
  // }
])
```

### Result

Which gives us:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "uid": "123456789101112131415161"
  }
]
```

Comment: I had already tried this and it didn't work either, thank you very much.